# dynamically placing a value in django query

Tags: django

I have following code:

```
hotels = models.Hotel.objects.filter(
            wed=True,
            county=hotel_main.county.id,
            subscriptions__end_date__gte=datetime.date.today(),
            subscriptions__enquiry_count__lte=F('subscriptions__tier__enquiry_limit'),
        ).filter(Q(x=TRUE|Q(y=True)).distinct()
```

And i have a list `test = ['x','y','z','w']`

The values of filter changes dynamically, so I use something like:

```
filter(Q(test[0]=TRUE|Q(test[3]=True))
```

which changes dynamically, but when I did that I got the following error:

```
Keyword can't be an expression
```

I know i can't use it there but let me know how to achieve this... Thank you!

#### Edit

I did as Chris suggested:

```
test[1] = {x: True}
```

and in my filter, I did as follows

```
filter(Q(test[1])).
```

it gave me below error:

```
need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary to set the keys and then expand it into kwargs with `**`, i.e.:

```
Q(**{test[0]: True})
```

Comment: can you make it bit more cleat